# Can I use some form of PHP and oAuth to serve raw files from a private git?

Tags: php, git, github

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to use PHP to my advantage so I can serve some stylesheets and javascripts from a private github repository for testing purposes before going live?

**The full story:**

I have a new, private git repository with a master branch and two sub-branches. My idea is for my fellow developer and I to push our changes to our respective sub-branches, and then add a query string variable to our PHP-based web app to tell it to serve stylesheets and javascripts from github.

For example something like:

1. Switch to your branch in Atom
2. Make some changes
3. Push and commit those changes
4. Go to a URL like "example.com/MyApp.php?User=Me"
5. MyApp.php will see the "User" query string var, and will prefix the necessary stylesheets and javascripts with a URL so they load directly from github
6. We can test Myapp.php and make sure we're happy, and then merge our changes with the master branch.
7. FTP our local changes to our live site

I like the idea of doing it this way because I can have one local set of files, which we only ever **FTP** to one spot on the live site, and only after the above steps have been completed. I don't have to worry about one of us accidentally FTPing to the live site instead of some testing folder or something, because during testing we'll only do github pushes, leaving the live site unchanged. Meanwhile, github will keep a nice history of versions etc if we need to backtrack for some reason. I have no plans to use github as an ongoing host or cdn. Once we're happpy with the changes and we've merged with master, we'll proceed to FTP the files to our live site, which will always serve from its own local directory.

Unfortunately there are two problems with this:

1. Github specifically doesn't allow hotlinking, hence sites like rawgit.com
2. I can't use rawgit since this is a private repository

So that brings me to the TL;DR. Is there some way I can use PHP to authorize my script so it can serve files from github? Maybe it can get a token or something? I suppose I can be really hacky and use cURL to simulate a login, grab some auth tokens and tack them on to URLs like raw.githubusercontent.com/....../java.js?token=.... But ugh, there must be a better way.

Alternatively is there a better way to go about our workflow? Keeping in mind I'd really like to avoid something like "during testing, FTP your files up to the dev folder, but during production, FTP them up to the live folder" - I feel like this is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Why are you not using GIT on the LIVE Site?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm new to git so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but doesn't the same problem of the private repository apply? How can I serve the files from git?

Comment: You dont serve files from a git repo. You put git on the live server and `pull` a tagged version from the master branch. There are also automated mechanism of doing it using git

Comment: Your workflow is broken. You don't serve files from a git repo, even in a test environment. You automate this CI/webhooks/integrations, etc.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't know that was even possible. I did some googling - is this what you mean? https://gist.github.com/Nilpo/8ed5e44be00d6cf21f22

Comment: Yea, thats what you shoudl be aiming at

Comment: @Sammitch That's all new to me as well, can you give me more information so I can read up on it? When you say 'you automate this' - what in particular  am I automating (assuming you're not talking about serving files from somewhere). what is CI / webhooks / integrations etc? Again I'm new to git so my apologies if this is old news to you. Thank you!

Comment: @RiggsFolly OK thanks - so I think that will get my live site synced with the master branch of the repo, which is great. What about a testing branches? Do I need to have a different folder on the live site called "MyApp_Dev" or something, and sync that with the appropriate testing branch?

Comment: You don't NORMALLY put dev code on the LIVE server. Don't you have a local testing lamp or wamp stack you use to develop code on?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not for this app, it's very integrated with the DB on the live site. I guess I'll have our host set up a dev.example.com copy of the live site for us, and we'll push the testing branches to dev until we're happy, then merge them with the master branch, which will be synced with the live site. Thanks for your help, that pretty much answers my question - the problem is not "how to serve test files from github" but instead I need to change the workflow plan. If you want to put your comments as an answer I'll mark it correct, thanks again.